# How to get a fixed amount of results per row?

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can I build a query with this format with a sqlite3 database?

```
CREATE TABLE sample (integer foo);
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (1);
...
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (10);
```

Format of the result

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to add some criteria to group them:

```
CREATE TABLE sample (integer foo, char(1) bar);
INSERT INTO sample VALUES
(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'b'), (5, 'b'), (6, 'b'), (7, 'c') ...;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(foo ORDER BY foo, ',')
FROM sample
GROUP BY bar
```

**Edit:**

Try this:

```
select group_concat(foo) from (
  select s1.foo, (count(*) - 1) / 3 grp from sample s1
  join sample s2 on s1.rowid >= s2.rowid
  group by s1.rowid
) final
group by grp
```

Comment: It is a good alternative, the actual data that I use in this context does not suffer much change, but if one is removed I would have to implement a logic units to include new value to the group that does not have three members and is not the latest.

But thank you for another point of view :)

Comment: I added another answer. It should survive deletions as it is dynamically calculated

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution (and has some edge cases---if you have a 3 value that is not null), and can probably be put into one query, but I needed the RowId to join on. It should do the trick, though:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE split1 (foo1 int);
CREATE TEMP TABLE split2 (foo2 int);
CREATE TEMP TABLE split3 (foo3 int);

INSERT INTO split1
SELECT foo FROM sample WHERE foo % 3 = 1 ORDER BY foo

INSERT INTO split2
SELECT foo FROM sample WHERE foo % 3 = 2 ORDER BY foo

INSERT INTO split3
SELECT foo FROM sample WHERE foo % 3 = 0 ORDER BY foo

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN foo2 IS NULL THEN foo1
        WHEN foo3 IS NULL THEN foo1||','||foo2
        ELSE foo1||','||foo2||','||foo3
    END
FROM split1
    LEFT JOIN split2 
        ON split1.RowId = split2.RowId
    LEFT JOIN split3
        ON split2.RowId = split3.RowId
```

Comment: I believe this way will be even more perfomartico implement this logic in a loop in the code. I could make an order to simplify the call.

thank you very much

There should exitir a query "magic" of a line for this task is not it?

Comment: @ErlonCabral You did not state that as a requirement. Let me see what I can do

Comment: @ErlonCabral Sorry, must this be a view, or can it be a parameterless stored procedure? This would require a recursive query otherwise, and per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456957/basic-recursive-query-on-sqlite3 ...this is not possible in SQLite. You are going to have to do this in your code base...or you could do Mostacho's implementation and make sure each one is attached to a grouping...which would be cumbersome...Those appear to be your only options