# Can I get ancestor element in a single query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys, parent-child, hierarchy

let's say I have a column named "parent" that references the ID column from the same table.
so it can empty or a number. if it's empty it means that the record has no parent.

Example:

```
ID  name  parent
1   A
2   B     1
3   C     2
4   D     2
```

to get the ancestor of C I make two queries:

```
SELECT parent FROM table WHERE id = 2

SELECT parent FROM table WHERE id = 1
```

then I get empty parent so I know 1 is the ancestor.

I was wondering if it's possible to do this in a single query :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [basic recursive query on sqlite3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456957/basic-recursive-query-on-sqlite3)

Comment: @Anna K. I added an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in a single query, but with `recursive_triggers` (SQLite>=3.6.18) you can do it with a fixed number of statements.

Check this (where `tt` is your table name):

```
-- Schema addition:
PRAGMA recursive_triggers=1;
CREATE TEMP TABLE ancid(id UNIQUE, ancestor);
CREATE TEMP TRIGGER ancid_t AFTER INSERT ON ancid WHEN (SELECT parent FROM tt WHERE id=NEW.ancestor) IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ancid SELECT NEW.id, parent FROM tt WHERE id=NEW.ancestor;
END;

-- Getting ancestor from id=3:
INSERT INTO ancid VALUES(3, 3);
SELECT * FROM ancid WHERE id=3;

-- Getting all ancestors:
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ancid SELECT id, id FROM tt;
SELECT * FROM ancid;
```

Comment: that create table and insert looks very expensive :P

Comment: @AnnaK. Yes, it is! But is plain SQLite. And using memory temporary tables, perhaps SQLite engine gets best performance than other programmatic solutions...

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is Using [Recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

in essence it will be. This is pseudo code but it will get you 90% there. If you give me some table definitions i can do more for you

```
;with coolCTE as (
SELECT id,NAME,1 as level
FROM tableX
where parent is null
union all
select id,name,level + 1
from tablex as y 
inner join coolcte as c on y.id = c.parentid
where y.parentid is not null
)
```

Comment: Please change your link to point to the relevant SQLite documentation.