# recursive sql search

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am looking for a query, where I can ask for data by groups. example:

```
table group
-uID-|-parentID-|-someData-
0    |  0       | foo
1    |  0       | bar
2    |  1       | foobar
3    |  2       | test
4    |  2       | demo
```

The parent ID is pointing to the uID from the parental group.

For example: when I want group 3 I will get back "test" only. When I request group 1, the results will be: bar, foobar, test and demo.
So I have to get all the rows, where the parentID matches my uID I am searching for.

Here is an image of the architecture for better understanding:
[image: Architecture of groups]

If I am looking for group 1, will get it and all the sub groups 2, 3 and 4.

Thank you.

Comment: I am using sqlite.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how you get bar, foobar, test and demo from requesting group 1?

Comment: Here's a question with example recursive queries in SQLite: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456957/basic-recursive-query-on-sqlite3

Comment: @BobbyA I have added an image for better understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sqlite we can use a [recursive CTE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) to pull this off.

```
WITH RECURSIVE reccte AS
(
    SELECT 
        uid as initialID,
        uID,
        parentID,
        someData,
        1 as depth 
    FROM table
    WHERE uID = 1 /*starting point for recursive stuff*/

    UNION ALL

    /*Recursive statement*/
    SELECT
        reccte.initialID,
        t1.uID,
        t1.parentID,
        someData,
        depth + 1
    FROM
        reccte
        INNER JOIN table as t1 ON
            recCTE.uID = t1.parentID /*joining up the parent*/
    WHERE depth < 15 /*keep from endless loops*/
)

/*Select all the someData's that resulted from the recursive lookup*/
SELECT someData FROM recCTE;
```

Comment: Without the `depth`, there would be no danger of endless loops.

Comment: I'm not familiar with sqlite. Does it have some mechanism in recursive queries to prevent endless cycling in the event that OP's actual data might not be clean?

Comment: UNION removes any duplicate rows. (If that is not needed, UNION ALL would be more efficient.)

Comment: please see my question again. i have added an image. thanks

Comment: @tom_tom This should give you the output you are looking for based on the hierarchy from your picture. `Child | Parent | attribute` tables are pretty common and recursive CTEs are how we generally solve these ones.

Comment: thanks a lot, with a little adaption, it worked perfectly for me!