# How do I join a table with itself to get the data's hierarchy

Tags: sql, sqlite, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

A section of my database includes a table saving information about blocks:

```
CREATE TABLE blocks (
    id_block INTEGER NOT NULL,
    id_type INTEGER NOT NULL,
    id_parent_block INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_block),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_type) REFERENCES block_types (id_block_type),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_parent_block) REFERENCES blocks (id_block)
) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

**1st**. I'm not sure about the **id_parent_block** being a foreign key, since it's a key present in the current table.

It is supposed to reflect some kind of hierarchy where blocks have blocks inside. Blocks that are on top have their **id_parent_block = -1**.

Blocks also have words in them:

```
CREATE TABLE words(
    id_word INTEGER NOT NULL,
    str_word TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_word),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_block) REFERENCES blocks (id_block),
) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

One block may have words (or not) and blocks (or not) in it.

**2nd**. How do I get all the **id_word**s associated to every block in a hierarchy of blocks where the block on top does not necessarily have id_parent_block = -1?

Comment: Look at CTE to implement recursive queries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456957/basic-recursive-query-on-sqlite3

Comment: It's fine to have a foreign key refer to the same table. But it's more usual to have null values for top level rows.

Comment: When your PK is a single integer column you should be using a normal table, not a `WITHOUT ROWID` one, btw. See section 4 of https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html