# How to find levels in a hierarchy by dates using SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, recursion, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data

### Problem

How to find a level for every individual in a hierarchy, by dates, using SQLite with recursive expression.

### Details

I have found the following [post detailing the use of recursive queries for doing computation on hierarchical data in SQLite](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/comparison/recursive_queries.html) and [that one on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456957/basic-recursive-query-on-sqlite3) for basic recursive queries on SQLite3.

Now, there is a good [detailed example on the documentation of SQLite](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html) about how to approach computation for hierarchical data from a single employee perspective (example at part 3.2).

### What have I managed to do?

Well, so far I know how to compute the levels for a selected individual (woohoo), but I can't bridge the gap and make this query **apply to all the individuals by dates**.

Here is my partial query that does the job for 1 individual:

```
WITH RECURSIVE supervisor_of(id, boss_id, date_interest) AS (
        SELECT org_1.id, org_1.boss_id, org_1.date_interest
        FROM org org_1
        WHERE id = 4 -- Here is the input for the individual
    UNION
        SELECT org_1.id, org_1.boss_id, org_1.date_interest
        FROM org org_1
        JOIN supervisor_of so
            ON so.boss_id = org_1.id
            AND so.date_interest = org_1.date_interest
)
SELECT *,
    COUNT(id) AS level
FROM supervisor_of
GROUP BY date_interest
ORDER BY date_interest
```

And the output:

```
| id   | boss_id | date_interest | level |
| ---- | ------- | ------------- | ----- |
| 4    | 2       | 2             | 3     |
| 4    | 2       | 3             | 3     |
```

But I can't manage to wrap around my head to get this result:

```
| id   | boss_id | date_interest | level |
| ---- | ------- | ------------- | ----- |
| 1    |         | 1             | 1     |
| 2    | 1       | 1             | 2     |
| 3    | 1       | 1             | 2     |
| 1    |         | 2             | 1     |
| 2    | 1       | 2             | 2     |
| 3    | 1       | 2             | 2     |
| 4    | 2       | 2             | 3     |
| 1    |         | 3             | 1     |
| 2    | 1       | 3             | 2     |
| 3    | 1       | 3             | 2     |
| 4    | 2       | 3             | 3     |
| 5    | 4       | 3             | 4     |
```

Here is how to load the data for making this test:

```
CREATE TABLE org(
  id TEXT,
  boss_id TEXT,
  date_interest TEXT
);
-- 1st Date
INSERT INTO org (id, boss_id, date_interest) VALUES(1, NULL, 1);
INSERT INTO org (id, boss_id, date_interest) VALUES(2, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO org (id, boss_id, date_interest) VALUES(3, 1, 1);
-- 2nd Date
INSERT INTO org (id, boss_id, date_interest) VALUES(1, NULL, 2);
INSERT INTO org (id, boss_id, date_interest) VALUES(2, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO org (id, boss_id, date_interest) VALUES(3, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO org (id, boss_id, date_interest) VALUES(4, 2, 2);
-- 3rd Date
INSERT INTO org (id, boss_id, date_interest) VALUES(1, NULL, 3);
INSERT INTO org (id, boss_id, date_interest) VALUES(2, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO org (id, boss_id, date_interest) VALUES(3, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO org (id, boss_id, date_interest) VALUES(4, 2, 3);
INSERT INTO org (id, boss_id, date_interest) VALUES(5, 4, 3);
```

Comment: Are you sure that in the last row of your expected results the level must be 3 and not 4?

Comment: Ah yes indeed, I wrongly input the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `WHERE` clause from your code so that you query for all `id`s and in the 2nd part of the recursive `CTE` select `supervisor_of.id` and not `org_1.id`.
Finally you must group by `id` also:

```
WITH RECURSIVE supervisor_of(id, boss_id, date_interest) AS (
  SELECT org_1.id, org_1.boss_id, org_1.date_interest
  FROM org org_1
  UNION
  SELECT so.id, org_1.boss_id, org_1.date_interest
  FROM org org_1 JOIN supervisor_of so
  ON so.boss_id = org_1.id AND so.date_interest = org_1.date_interest
)
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS level
FROM supervisor_of
GROUP BY date_interest, id
ORDER BY date_interest, id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=cc58787eb8e5cca243c2b666901c7d77).
Results:

| id | boss_id | date_interest | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | null | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | null | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 | 3 | 4 |

Comment: Wow, I have to say thanks a lot, seriously I have been working on this for days, and it is a godsend !